# How can I split one file into 2 small ones tkinter gui?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a file called ran.py in which I have a button created that should change the color of the main window:

```
from tkinter import *
import gui
win = Tk()

b = Button(win, command=color)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

In a file called gui.py I have a command that should change the background color:

```
win.configure(bg="red")
```

I have tried many things but it always fails with the following error:
win.configure(bg="red") NameError: name 'win' is not defined
How do I do it so that the background color changes when I click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a `color()` function inside `gui.py` like below:

```
def color():
    win.configure(bg='red')
```

and the `command` option of `b` should be as below:

```
b = Button(win, command=gui.color)
```

If this is the case, you will get the said error as `win` is not inside `gui` scope.

You should pass `win` as an argument to `color()` inside `gui.py`:

```
def color(win):
    win.configure(bg='red')
```

And then modify `command` option as below:

```
b = Button(win, command=lambda: gui.color(win))
```